# loop through Json structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Question: Just wondering , what is the best way to loop items in the inner structure of a Json file. Like "showtimes" key here ?

My Json file:

```
var movies_list = {
    "movies":[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Finding Nemo",
      "audience":"UA",
      "language":"english",
      "genre":[  
         "kids",
         "adventure"
      ],
      "running_time":"120",
      "showtimes":[  
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"10:00 AM",
            "showtime_code":1000
         },
         {  
            "cinema_name":"PVR",
            "display_showtime":"1:00 PM",
            "showtime_code":1300
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Incredibles",
      "audience":"UA",
      "language":"english",
      "genre":[  
         "kids",
         "thriller"
      ],
      "running_time":"190",
      "showtimes":[  
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"8:00 AM",
            "showtime_code":0800
         },
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"2:00 PM",
            "showtime_code":1400
         }
      ]
   }
]
};
```

Iterating the first loop is working fine. Just want to loop through the items present in "showtimes" key.

My code:

```
var data = movies_list.movies;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   var fisrtLoopData = data[i];
   $('body').append('<p>'+ fisrtLoopData + '</p>');
}
```

Comment: You are already there. Just add another for loop for  fisrtLoopData.showtimes

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var data = movies_list.movies;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   var showtimes = data[i].showtimes
   for (var j=0; j<showtimes.length; j++){
        var items = showtimes[j]
       $('body').append('<p>'+ items.cinema_name + '</p>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . It works ! Just one question: This way can i consume data from a REST API ? or there are other simple ways to do it ?

Comment: that would depends on what you want to do with the data you get back from the API. please, update your question and I will update the answer.

Comment: I meant, if JSON file structure is complex... then solution provided by you is fine to work with ?

Comment: no, the way you access the data you want depends on the complexity of the JSON data. I suggest that you have a look at the data coming back from the API and if you need further update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  var data = movies_list;  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k){        
    for(var i = 0; i < movies_list[k].length; i++){
       var fisrtLoopData = movies_list[k][i]["name"] + " " + movies_list[k][i]["audience"];
       $('body').append('<p>'+ fisrtLoopData + '</p>');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Your `JSON` is not valid.

[image]

A leading `0` at **`"showtime_code": 0800`** indicates an `octal number` in JavaScript. An octal number cannot contain an `8`, therefor, that number is invalid. `JSON` doesn't (officially) support `octal` numbers, even if the number does not contain an `8`.

**Correction :** If you have a number, don't store it with leading `zero`. If you have a value that needs to have a leading zero, don't treat it as a `number`, but as a `string`. Store it with quotes around it.

[image]

**`JSON` Parsing :** Use JavaScript [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to parse the `JSON` to get the required data.

**DEMO**

```js
var movies_list = {
    "movies":[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Finding Nemo",
      "audience":"UA",
      "language":"english",
      "genre":[  
         "kids",
         "adventure"
      ],
      "running_time":"120",
      "showtimes":[  
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"10:00 AM",
            "showtime_code":1000
         },
         {  
            "cinema_name":"PVR",
            "display_showtime":"1:00 PM",
            "showtime_code":1300
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Incredibles",
      "audience":"UA",
      "language":"english",
      "genre":[  
         "kids",
         "thriller"
      ],
      "running_time":"190",
      "showtimes":[  
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"8:00 AM",
            "showtime_code":800
         },
         {  
            "cinema_name":"Suncity",
            "display_showtime":"2:00 PM",
            "showtime_code":1400
         }
      ]
   }
]
};

var arr = [];
var res = movies_list.movies.map(function(item) {
  for (var i in item.showtimes) {
    arr.push(item.showtimes[i].cinema_name);
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I think best time to use map.

Comment: I don't think you need a map there, since you are not doing anything with the `res` array which you'll get after the map with `[undefined, undefined]`. You could rather use a `forEach`

Comment: @MuraliKrishna I am not using res array but what i am doing is i am iterating the `movies` array through `map` function.

Comment: @LipakSahil Your welcome !! If it fulfill your expectation mark it as a correct so that it will be useful for others also.

Comment: @Rohit but the `map` will return an array with the same length as movies, with `undefined` values in it since you are not returning anything inside the function. But in your case you are not expecting any return value right, only the loop for that `forEach` is the right thing to use. I mean you can use the `map`, but the purpose of the `map` is different

Answer (score 0):

```
movies_list.movies.forEach(function(movie) { 
    movie.showtimes.forEach(function(showtime) {
       console.log(showtime.cinema_name)
    });
});
```

in a functional way. You actually don't need any loops.